# Catch 'Template parse errors' in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to catch 'Template parse errors' in angular and log them in some custom way using ErrorHandler but can't find a way to catch them. Is it possible?
Supposedly all errors should be handled via ErrorHandler but these 'Template parse errors' are not. Any ideas how to catch them?

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK, template parse errors are compile time errors, not run-time errors. The code does not run when it finds template parse errors so there is no ErrorHandler running. Can you expand on what you are trying to do?

Comment: it is actually a run time error: when element does not exist but is referenced in the template angular throws this exception:
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'element-name' is not a known element:
I just need a way to log this error back to the server so need to catch it. But it does not go thru the ErrorHandler

Comment: I also would like to know how to do this! Broken dynamic HTML being output in the template is the issue I have. Only thing I can think of is an intermediate HTML parse/validation step in the component (but I'm new to Angular).